# New tag (and wiki) for employment bonds (common in India)?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems that in India, it is common for new employees to sign an **employment bond** (or simply **bond**) - meaning they agree to pay a certain sum of money if they leave their employment before a certain timescale (typically 1-3 years).

Similar agreements exist in other countries, but usually only if the employee is provided specific training by the employer (for example, "we will pay this training for you, but you will have to pay it back if you leave within a year"). Employment bonds are different in that they are generally (as far as I understand) not based on training provided, but simply used as a way to retain employees.

Further reading:

- [Employee Bond and its legal acceptability in India](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/employee-bond-its-legal-acceptability-india-jai-nagwan)
- [Validity of Employment Bonds in India](https://indiacorplaw.in/2018/07/validity-employment-bonds-india.html)
- [IT firm banks on guarantee | Hyderabad News - Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/hyderabad/IT-firm-banks-on-guarantee/articleshow/2148886.cms)

We have several questions about this in this site (just [search for "bond india"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=bond+india)), but no tag, let alone a tag wiki.

Is there any opposition to introducing a tag for this? I propose:

> employment-bond

I'd also add a short tag wiki:

> Employment bond, or bond, an agreement between an employee and their employer, which requires the employee to pay a certain sum of money if they leave their employment before a certain timespan (typically one to three years after the start of employment). Particularly common in India.

Comment: When you say "Particularly common in India", it makes me think that it's... pretty common in India. Not pretty common relative to other places. (I do not know how to word it better).

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: To me, "particularly common" implies "more common than in general" - but I'm not a native speaker. Feel free to propose a different wording :-).

Answer (score 4):

As there was no response (and some upvotes), I went ahead and created the 
tag:

[employment-bond](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment-bond)

I also wrote a short tag wiki, and tagged some applicable questions.

Comment: Are all the questions on the site where people ask about having to payback money for training and moving expenses going to be added to this tag?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Good question. AFAIK, the term "bond" is only widely used in India - however, the concept exists elsewhere. In many countries, there are legal limits for such "bonds" - e.g. in Germany they may only be imposed for repayment of specific cost incurred by the company (such as training). Also, such repayment agreements can be made after hiring, while an employment bond typically starts with the employment. I'll edit the tag wiki to make the distinction clearer.

Comment: Sometimes it is also known as "service agreement".

Comment: +1 - should it be mentioned or linked to the [relieving-letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relieving-letter) tag?

Comment: @rath: I don't see a direct connection between the two - but if you do, feel free to edit the tag.

Comment: @sleske I don't either, but I'm not familiar with either topic. I thought they might be related, if they're not, no worries :)